# Worksheet SaveAs not inheriting workbook custom properties

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to save a worksheet as a new workbook but in doing so the custom properties of the initial workbook are not being inherited.

```
' Set the workbook properties
ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.item("customProp1") = variableOne
ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.item("customProp2") = variableTwo

' Save the worksheet as a new workbook
Worksheets("Sheet1").SaveAs FileName:=documentName
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

I've had an extensive search and I can't find a solution to this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is possible, however I did come up with a solution. It silently opens up the workbook that needs the custom properties, gives it the custom properties, saves it and then closes it down.

```
Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = False 'Visible is False by default, so this isn't necessary
Dim book As Excel.Workbook

Set book = app.Workbooks.Add(documentName)

    With book.CustomDocumentProperties
        .Add Name:="property1", _
            LinkToContent:=False, _
            Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, _
            Value:="One"
        .Add Name:="property2", _
            LinkToContent:=False, _
            Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, _
            Value:="two"
    End With

    app.DisplayAlerts = False
    book.Close FileName:=documentName, SaveChanges:=True
    app.Quit
Set app = Nothing
```